Why does build time increase when using docker-compose with "args"?
Why does build time increase when using docker-compose with "args"?
I have a compose file that has the following:
build:
 context: /docker/container-setups/user
 dockerfile: user_webserver.dockerFile
 args:
 - db_hostname=${USER_ID}_database

and the dockerFile:
FROM php:apache
ARG db_hostname

Without docker-compose args, the container is started 20 seconds faster.
If instead of compose I use docker build --build-arg, it goes just as fast as if I had excluded the args.
So can someone please explain why the build time slows down when I include args with docker-compose and if I can do something different to make it work faster

Is that literally the entire Dockerfile?  Providing an ARG value can result in invalidating Docker's build cache, which could cause later RUN statements to be re-run, but that doesn't seem to be what you're seeing there.  (I wouldn't usually include a deployment-specific setting like a database host name as a build-time argument, though.)

@DavidMaze Yes that's the entire dockerFile. If i remove ARG and just have "args:" in the .yml file then the build is as fast as it should, but that's pointless. Don't understand why 20 sec is added just for one simple arg
